# Error when i try to save a product with a null value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am making a management product program (to use in a store).

I have 4 models, the principal is Product.

The last 3 are: Provider, Branch and Category.

These 3 models are related with product in a one to many relationship.

In some cases, I don't want to put a provider or branch in a product, when I try this I get this error:

```
"errors": {"CategoryId": ["The value '' is invalid."]
```

This is the model of Product:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Codebar { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int Stock { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Price { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public Provider Provider { get; set; }

    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
}
```

Post method of Product:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> PostProduct([FromForm]ProductDTO productDTO)
{
    try
    {
        Category newCategory = _context.Category.Single(x => x.Id == productDTO.CategoryId);
        Provider newProvider = _context.Provider.Single(x => x.Id == productDTO.ProviderId);
        Branch newBranch = _context.Branch.Single(x => x.Id == productDTO.BranchId);

        Product newProduct = new( 
        {
            Name = productDTO.Name,
            Stock = productDTO.Stock,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Price = productDTO.Price,
            Codebar = productDTO.Codebar,
            Category = newCategory,
            Provider = newProvider,
            Branch = newBranch
        };
                
        _context.Products.Add(newProduct);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return CreatedAtAction("GetProduct", 
            new { id = newProduct.Id }, newProduct);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

And this is the branch model (category and provider are the same):

```
public class Branch
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

I really appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: Try to set the CategoryId  explicitly when you create new product.

Comment: Can you confirm, or update your code example to demonstrate the situation where you get an error?  Your comment "In some cases, i dont want to put a provider or branch in a product" sounds like you want the Provider, branch, and possibly Category to be optional. These are defined as required by virtue that their FK in product is `int` rather than `int?`/`Nullable<int>` which would allow them to be optional.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i resolve the problem!